# Unix processes wasn't killed but is not running

Tags: process

I have a system where some custom software is running, and then may receive a `SIGHUP`. As a result of the `SIGHUP`, the process does some cleanup and terminates, but it doesn't terminate its long running child processes.

After the system was running for several months (and in the course of that many of my processes had the misfortune of being hanged up on), I can see in my Ubuntu 12.04 server that I have many of the child processes that have init as their parent, but they are not running nor stopped or zombie - ps shows them in "sleep" state.

If I try to strace one of these processes, the process starts running then immediately sees that it trying to process files that are no longer there (temporary files that were created and deleted some months ago) and exits:

```
# strace -fp 16111
Process 16111 attached - interrupt to quit
open("/tmp/some-file", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "/tmp/some-file:"..., 59) = 59
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
Process 16111 detached
```

This also happens if I try to `kill -STOP <pid>` (at least I guess it does - after I send the signal, the process disappears).

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Looks like the process is blocked on IO. So if the file gets missing, only timeout or signal can unblock it. But it depends a lot on the code. This is just a supposition.

Comment: While your supposition kind of makes sense because the parent process has a FIFO that is read by the child process, which obviously closes when the parent is hanged up, but if the process is blocked on IO, I would expect it status to be `D` not `S`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process may have received one of the terminal stop signals. Those may be send if a background process tries to communicate with the terminal. There are three types of terminal stop signals: `TSTP`, `TTIN`, and `TTOU`. My first guess is the process tried to read from the terminal while it was backgrounded, and thus got send a `TTIN` signal. By the time you resume it by attaching strace, there no longer is a terminal, so it gets an error code instead of a signal, if the read is retried. Another way to unfreeze the process is by sending it a `CONT` signal.

Comment: The attachment to a terminal makes sense as the main process was started from an SSH command (that was disconnected after backgrounding the process), but from my testing all the signals mentioned above cause the process to get into a `T` state, while the processes I have problem with are in the `S` state. Also, sending them `CONT` has no effect.

Comment: The ptrace implementation in the kernel makes use of signal internally in a way, which unfortunately sometimes affects the behavior of programs. The first line or two of the strace output might provide a hint. The wchan column of ps output while the process is sleeping might provide a hint as well. `ps -o user,pid,ppid,lstart,tname,wchan,cmd` may be a useful selection of columns to look at in your case.

Comment: All the relevant processes have either `pipe_w` under "wchan", or `wait` (for shell processes waiting on the blocked processes). What does it mean?

Comment: `pipe_w` sounds like it may be blocked trying to write to a pipe. That would indicate that the process at the reading end of that pipe is not actually reading from it. I can't say why this would change from using strace, which is why I asked for the first two lines of the strace output. I have seen a similar problem happen when starting a program with `ssh -fX` where the program was also writing to stdout or stderr. It would write until the pipe buffer was full and then the window would freeze. Through /proc I was able to find the read end owned by `sshd` and read from it to clear the buffer.

Comment: According to `ls -l /proc/XX/fd` both 0, 1 and 2 fds are pointed to `/dev/null`. I've updated the question with the strace output. Thanks.

Comment: Does the process not have any other open file descriptors? It shouldn't be possible to end up in `pipe_wait` with `/dev/null` as the only open file. In a multithreaded program it may be possible for one thread to start operating on a file descriptor and for another thread to close that file descriptor, while the first is still blocked on it. That would be a terrible design. The WCHAN column is too narrow by default, you can get the full name by putting that column last or write something like `wchan:20` in the ps command.

Comment: sorry, apparently the fds all pointing at null is not a common case. Usually it looks like this: `0 -> pipe:[6754400]` `1 -> pipe:[6754401]` `2 -> pipe:[6754402]` `3 -> /mount/ebs1/tmp/user/1001/20140220-28920-p041mk.wav (deleted)`

Comment: What's at the other end of those pipes? In the above case you could use something like `ls -l /proc/*/fd/* | grep pipe..675440` to see both ends of the pipes.

Comment: The other end of the pipe was a process that was terminated a long time ago.

Comment: I would check that one more time, because it is not supposed to be possible to be blocking on a pipe, if the other end of said pipe has been closed.

Comment: All the stuck processes that I see have pipes connected somewhere (not necessarily 0~2, some have the std pipes connected to `/dev/null` and have pipes in 10~12), and all these pipes are unique in the system - i.e. grepping for them in `/proc/*/fd` returns a single result.

Comment: `/dev/null` is a character device, not a pipe. If only one end of a pipe is open, it should be impossible to block on it. Reading from a pipe where the write end is closed gives 0 immediately (meaning end of file). Writing to a pipe where the read end is closed results in a `SIGPIPE` signal. The other end might not show up when looking at `/proc/*/fd` if it is only open by a specific thread or if it is currently being passed over a unix socket between two processes. But that should not change from attaching strace to the process. I am wondering if you have been hitting some deadlock bug in the

Comment: The system is old 12.04 that has not been updated a while (I'm thinking at least a year), and running on EC2 - so any of these could cause weird behavior. I'm thinking of accepting your answer because its awesome how you covered what is important, and then I'll just kill all the stuck processes on my server.